# How can I efficiently query products with many-to-many ingredients and nested products?

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I currently have three tables: `product`, `ingredient`, and `product_ingredient` (m2m relationship).

[image: Product Ingredient relationship diagram]

A product has many ingredients and nested products through `product_ingredient`. The nested products themselves have many ingredients and nested products.

How can I efficiently query these relationships so that a single query can select a product's ingredients through multiple levels of nested relationships?

- The product ingredients should be ordered by their position `int`, with respect to its `product_id`.
- Each level of nested ingredients need to be grouped and ordered by the product they're related to.
- The entities are read more frequently than written, so *read* optimized would be preferred if there are any cache-based approaches (like materialized views).
- The actual structure has foreign keys on the `ingredient` table which are aggregated in different ways.

For example:

```sql
> select * from product;
 id | name
----+------------------------
  1 | chocolate
  2 | chocolate chip cookies

> select * from ingredient;
 id | name
----+--------------
  1 | cocoa
  2 | cocoa butter
  3 | flour
  4 | eggs
  5 | baking soda

> select * from product_ingredient;
 id | product_id | ingredient_id | nested_product_id | position
----+------------+---------------+-------------------+----------
  1 |          1 |             2 |            (null) |        0
  2 |          1 |             1 |            (null) |        1
  3 |          2 |             3 |            (null) |        0
  4 |          2 |             4 |            (null) |        1
  5 |          2 |        (null) |                 1 |        2
  6 |          2 |             5 |            (null) |        3
```

My ideal query would produce the following output:

```sql
> select ...;
 product_id |           product_name | ingredient_id | ingredient_name | position
------------+------------------------+---------------+-----------------+----------
          2 | chocolate chip cookies |             3 | flour           |        0
          2 | chocolate chip cookies |             4 | eggs            |        1
          1 |              chocolate |             2 | cocoa butter    |        0
          1 |              chocolate |             1 | cocoa           |        1
          2 | chocolate chip cookies |             5 | baking soda     |        3
```

*Note that the sort order is maintained using `position` through the nested relationships.*

Additionally, how do I prevent a circular relationships, where a `product_ingredient` references a `nested_product_id` that is a parent or grandparent relation? Is there a `CONSTRAINT` that I can use?

Comment: What’s wrong with your model? A recursive query can retrieve all ingredients.

Comment: Postgresql supports Common Table Expressions, which let you query recursively: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/queries-with.html

Comment: Also, the meaning of `nested_product_id` isn't clear: does it refer to a product that _contains_ the product referred to by `product_id`, or does it refer to a product that is _contained by_ the product referred to by `product_id`? You might want to choose a name that is more clear.

Comment: hm it is possiböle to create a a pearlctring of products that need only one additional ingredient, but usually you need a bunch if ingredients and myve some more aditional other combined products, so you should have in  bithe cases a bridf atble between then, Or you reaaly have such a pearl string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Database design for products with bundles of products](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129638/database-design-for-products-with-bundles-of-products)

Comment: Also see: http://www.softwaregems.com.au/Documents/Student%20Resolutions/Bill%20of%20Materials.pdf

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Using a CTE is likely the best tool for this. How do I use a CTE query to select the ingredient rows in the format and order I wrote in my example? Also, how do I optimize the query so that it's efficient for products with 4+ levels of nesting with hundreds of ingredients? I added more info to my question. Thank you!

Comment: @bbaird I wasn't specific enough in my question. The schema is similar, but what I'm asking is how to efficiently query the ingredients, and prevent circular references. I've edited my question to add more info. Thank you for your help!